# Make image height continually increase when screen is touched

Tags: android, timer, touch-event

I have an image within a relative layout and a linear layout below the image. This image is transparent so it looks like nothing is there.

My code adds 3 text views to the linear layout.

I have it so that when I move my finger on the screen it enlarges height of the image, thus giving the impression that the linear layout has moved down the screen.

I want to get it so that when the screen is being touched, so even if the finder is still, the image gets bigger, making it look like the image is moving down the screen. When the finger is removed the image stops enlarging.

I've been trying to create a thread to run onTouchEvent for about 2 weeks now, but my code just seems to crash the app.

Could someone amend my code / add this functionality so I can see where I'm going wrong. I'm hoping I'm just not putting the thread in the correct location or i'm not stopping the thread correctly which is causing it to crash.

**My Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Spacer"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="Spacer"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Letters"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@id/Spacer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My Activity**

```
package com.example.zz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected int splashTime = 3000;

    TextView tv1;
    ImageView spacer;
    String[] name = {"Hello","Rich","You","Hero"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] letters = {"A","B","C"};
        String letter = "";
        String nextLetters = "";

        for( int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        {
            letter = letters[i];
            nextLetters = nextLetters + letter;

            // Create a textView in code
            LayoutParams paramsExample = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);
            View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.Letters);
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this); 
            tv1.setText(letter); 
            tv1.setLayoutParams(paramsExample);
            tv1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(tv1);
        } 
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                spacer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Spacer);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)spacer.getLayoutParams();
                head_params.height = 400;
                spacer.setLayoutParams(head_params);

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am just using the launch icon as the image.

Any help would easy my hair loss, thanks in advance.

Comment: oh then i would like to see you bald ha ha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a boolean that is false. If ACTION_MOVE is called you set it true and when ACTION_UP is called you set it false again.

Then you call run every x milliseconds by using the handler

implement runnable and assign the handler

```
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

In on create:

```
    handler.postDelayed(this,TIME);
```

Then call run:

```
    @Override
    public void run(){
         if (yourboolean == true){
              spacer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Spacer);

              RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)spacer.getLayoutParams();
              head_params.height += 100;
              spacer.setLayoutParams(head_params);   

         }

         handler.postDelayed(this,TIME);
    }
```